# arm64 docker image for apple silicon M1 macbook air

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apple-m1, arm64, fast-ai

While trying to run the docker image provided by fastai --> [fastpages-jekyll](https://hub.docker.com/r/fastai/fastpages-jekyll) I am running into several issues.

This is a linux/amd64 image. I suspect that if there was a linux/arm64 image then it would run smoothly on my mackbook air M1 having apple silicon chip. I could not find such a pre-existing image on docker hub.

Also I cannot find Dockerfile associated with fastpages-jekyll image.

Is it possible to build an arm64 image from the amd64 image somehow ?
What are my options ?

Comment: I have basically the same question; my impression is that there is no such docker image yet. I managed to set up an (amazingly fast) tensorflow with the metal GPU plugin, but could not find a docker image yet. (And I found out that Docker for Mac would not allow GPU use, so my motivation is reduced anyhow now, but I would still be interested.)

Answer (score 0):

[This github](https://github.com/sonoisa/arm64-docker-pytorch-tensorflow) is the source for pre-built [arm64 (Apple Silicon) docker images with PyTorch](https://hub.docker.com/r/sonoisa/deep-learning-coding). That said, you'll still need to install fastai inside this image.

I am currently working on a new version of [my "native" fastai image (which uses the above image as a base image)](https://hub.docker.com/r/tedsecretsource/deep-learning-coding-fastai2.5) that will not require sonisa's base image and will include Ruby (so you can run a Ruby on Rails server that can access pickle files created by fastai). However, that's still a work in progress. Watch [this repo](https://github.com/tedsecretsource/ror-fastai) as I hope to publish the new docker file in the coming days.